# SVN keyword $Date: $ change date format to DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS

Tags: date, svn, formatting, keyword

I use the SVN keyword $Date: $ to show the last change date.

checkinDate: $Date: $

=> 
checkinDate: $Date: 2020-06-16 14:40:09 +0200 (Di, 16 Jun 2020) $

Now I need the date string in the following format.
checkinDate: $Date: 2020.06.16 14:40:09 $

Is there a possibility to change this format or a hook like this?

checkinDateInt: $Date: 2020-06-16 14:40:09 +0200 (Di, 16 Jun 2020) $
checkinDate:

Answer (score 0):

1. $DATE$ is always expanded with local time zone
2. No, you can't change format of date-string in SVN (except recompiling sources)

You can try to change Long Date format in your OS and compare results, but, anyway, if you want to have custom configurable keywords, you can:

- use SVN 1.8+, which have (some type of) "custom [user-level keywords](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html)" and `%d`placeholder + short-date format for your needs is OS
- migrate to Mercurial, it which you can build any [keywords](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/KeywordExtension) with any format